# Uploading video or audio to firebase using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to upload a record, an audio, from my local storage (immediately after instructing the app to stop recording) it is a voice to speech app, I get it to start recording and it stops after a period of 1min as I had programmed it, I try to get the record using the path which I had written it to but I just don't know how to go about it, even more I have been searching youtube, I see more of uploading images to firebase firestore using kotlin, please I need to upload a video or audio file using kotlin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, I will present my code